# ComboBox Binding error

Tags: c#, wpf

If I have a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SampleComboBox" Width="100" Margin="10, 0, 40, 0" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedSamplesNames}"  />
```

I have a property that this ComboBox is binding to when my items are selected in an associated table.  So when my application loads its data, it crashes with this error:

> InavlidOperationException was unhandled
>   {"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."}
>
> InnerException:null
>
> Message:Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>
> No disassembly.

I'm not sure why I get this error.  When I first populated the ComboBox with a different property, the SamplesNameList, which is a List of names that gets created from the data, no problem.  Now that I want to modify the ComboBox, to be bound to only the selected items of these names in a Table, I get this error. Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some item binding structures of the ones you used before and after the change?

Comment: what is the type of collection?

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you modify the collection in a background thread.

Don't do that; most collections are not thread safe.

Comment: I can't seem to find which collection is being modified.  No selection happens when the data is loaded, so that Collection is not being modified.

Comment: Turn on Break on All Exceptions and look at the Locals up the call stack; that may help.